# Case statement query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, case

Can I use case statement on a field to change the value of another field? Something like that,

```
SELECT  TaskDescription, 
CASE 
When TaskDescription='Lab Dips / Handloom Sent' then seq ='1'  
When TaskDescription='Lab Dips / Handloom Approve' then seq ='2' end,seq FROM SomeTable
```

I have some description of tasks in TaskDescription column, that I want to fetch in a certain order. That's why I want to add a seq number to each task description value so that I can get the expected order just writing 'order by seq'

Comment: You can't change field values in `SELECT` statement.  You can change the value of output *column* though.  You may want to post sample data and the desired result to clarify your requirements.

Comment: Then how can it be done?

Comment: You use `UPDATE` to change field values in a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want update value of table , you can use this :

```
Update SomeTable
Set seq = '1'
Where TaskDescription='Lab Dips / Handloom Sent'
```

Update :

```
Select TaskDescription ,seq 
From (
      SELECT  TaskDescription, 
            (CASE 
             When TaskDescription='Lab Dips / Handloom Sent' then 1 
             When TaskDescription='Lab Dips / Handloom Approve' then 2
           end) As seq FROM SomeTable
     ) As TB 
Order by TB.seq
```

Or :

```
With tb As (
    SELECT  TaskDescription
           ,(CASE TaskDescription
             When 'Lab Dips / Handloom Sent' then 1 
             When 'Lab Dips / Handloom Approve' then 2
          end) As seq 
     FROM SomeTable
)
Select * from tb
Order by tb.seq
```